# How do I implement a "dispatch_once" method, not for multi-thread environment, but to run only once when all criteria are met

Tags: ios, multithreading, algorithm, cocoa, key-value-observing

I need a "dispatch once" mechanism that when all the criteria are met, say both A&B are true, run that part of codes once, but only once. So when later on, if all the criteria are met again (both A&B are true again but I don't care then), the code won't run again.

I don't think dispatch_once is a good fit here. There is no data synchronization issue here, just later on all the criteria may be met again. Right now I try 2 methods:

1. KVO all the criteria, once they are met, run the code and stop KVO.
2. Add another property, update it when some criterion is met. When all the criteria are met, run the code, then set it to a special value, which will prevent the codes from running again. For example, set its initial value to 1, when A is true &2, when B is true &4, so when it is 7, run the codes and set its value to 0. Then later on, it will never be 7 again.

So it there a better way?

---- update ----

Except for knowing how many ways I can do this, I am also looking for a "systemic" way to do it. Right now I need to run part 1 once when A&B are both true; part 2 once when C&D&E are true; part 3 once when E&F are true. I used both methods I mentioned. The codes look messy and it is hard for others to understand what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this to happen only once per application I see nothing wrong with:

```
- (void)tryOnce{
    if (a && b){
         dispatch_once()...
    }
}
```

How you determine when to run that `if` is *totally* up to your specific implementation.  Using KVO on `a` and `b` seems appropriate if they can be modified in multiple locations, or you could override the setters:

```
- (void)setA(id a) {
     _a = a;
     [self tryOnce];
}
- (void)setB(id B) {
     _b = b;
     [self tryOnce];
}
```

--- Edit for OP's update ---

One general solution would be to create a class that holds two blocks and overrides `observeValueForKeypath:...`.  This lets you avoid a lot of messy checks in your (probably) UIViewController's `observeValueForKeyPath` and is generally a nice pattern anywhere you find yourself dealing with many calls into the same method (UITextView delegates, etc...).

```
@implementation ObserveAndDoOnce
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context{
    if (!self.checkBlock || !self.finishedBlock){ return; }
    if (self.checkBlock()) { // checkBlock returns a BOOL
        self.finishedBlock();
        self.checkBlock = nil;
        self.finishedBlock = nil;
    }
}
@end

ObserveAndDoOnce *a_and_b = [ObserveAndDoOnce new];
[self addObserver:a_and_b forKeyPath:keypath_for_a...];
[self addObserver:a_and_b forKeyPath:keypath_for_b...];
a_and_b.checkBlock = ...
a_and_b.finishedBlock = ...
```

Comment: But I don't see the value added when using dispatch_once

Comment: It totally depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  There's nothing harmful about `dispatch_once`.  If you don't like it you could add a property or static var like `didTryOnce` and then do `if (a && b && !didTryOnce)...`.  `dispatch_once` will only be run a maximum of once per application run  **guaranteed** whereas if you go the `didTryOnce` route there's a chance you might deallocate your object or otherwise reset `didTryOnce` and have thus have that code segment run again later.

Comment: Updated my question about what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Qiulang That makes things more clear.  I've updated my answer with a general method that I employ to handle this type of problem.

Comment: Thanks, let me think about it and get back to you later.